# ifxpy module cannot be installed using pip

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pip

i am trying to install this a flask project on another server but later realized it was failing at ifxpy during the

```
pip install -r requirements
```

The github link for the project is  https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy. Is there a way i can install it from the github repository.

Comment: What is the problem? Any error messages?

Comment: i found out that it only works with python 3.7